# Palindrome in an array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, time-complexity, palindrome

You are given an array of strings. You need to find out total number of pairs (a, b) such that a and b are palindromes. Example: html, xml, lmth, css, lmx, xhtml.  Here total count of pairs = 2 because the pairs (html, lmth) & (xml, lmx) are palindromic pairs. The brute force approach is O(n^2) solution.

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{           
    for(int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a[j]);
        sb = sb.reverse();

        if(a[i].equals(sb.toString()))
            count++;
    }
}
```

The program slows down as N increases. So what is the most efficient way to find out palindromic pairs such that time complexity is < O(n^2).

Comment: If you simply sort the original array (`O(nlog(n))`), you can then use dichotomic search (`O(log(n))`) to find the palindrome so you get a total `O(nlog(n))`.

Comment: @Holt - Can you please give any reference to dichotomic search. I don't find any good theory or implementation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search, in Java you have a direct acces to `binarySearch` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) through `Arrays.utils.binarySearch`. Dichotomic search is the general term, binary search is applied to a 1-d sorted array (actually I did a bad translation from french where « Dichotomie » = « Binary Search »).

Comment: See my answer for a (simple) implementation using binary search and comparison of the three methods.

Comment: one case that your solution (and the current solutions below) are missing is the case when it is not mirrored. (ex. `ab`, `cba`, where `abcba` is a palindrome) @Holt @skypjack

Answer (score 1):

I'd use two sets containing the string and its reversed form, as it follows (I'll try to reuse your code):

```
Set<String> def = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> rev = new HashSet<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a[i]);
    sb.reverse();
    String srev = sb.toString();

    if(rev.contains(a[i]) || def.contains(srev))
        ++count;

    def.add(a[i]);
    rev.add(srev);
}
```

The complexity still increases with `N` because you have to visit each string at least once, but it is no longer the square of `N`.

Anyway, even the code below should work.
I'm going to explain why in a few minutes.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a[i]);

    if(set.contains(sb.reverse().toString()))
        ++count;

    set.add(a[i]);
}
```

The idea here is that, for each string, you check if it's reversed form has been already visited, then you put in the set the initial form.

In an array, the two strings you are looking for are obviously at different locations. When you encounter the first one, its reversed form is not in the set, thus you do not increase the counter. When you encounter the second one, its reversed form is in the set, because it's the original string previously encountered, so you increase the counter only once.

This solution has problems if you have arrays like: [xml, lmx, lmx], but I don't know what you expect in these cases (anyway, you can use a multi set or a hash map and remove elements from the set to achieve different results).

Comment: How can set help here? I need to check for all palindromic pairs possible. It is still in O(n^2) time complexity. Though you have used only 1 loop but that 's still incorrect  I guess.

Comment: You are right, I forgot a set. Let me fix the code.

Comment: Assuming `j` _is_ `i`, you might still argue time consumption (esp. assumptions about HashSet). (chapeau for declaring `set` as `Set<String>`.) (You might supply a count to the constructor, and re-think the loop's upper bound.)

Comment: Sorry, `j` is `i` indeed. Fixed. How does supplying a count to the constructor could help? You mean avoiding dynamically internal allocation of the Set once you reach the limit, are you? Ok, it makes sense. Anyway, time consumption of the overall solution should be far lower than `O(N^2)`, for looking for an element in a set is not O(N).

Comment: @skypjack The complexity is the same as the 2 loops, it's `O(n^2)`, you get `n` loops, 1st loop the set search take `0`, 2nd take `1`, 3rd `2` and so on til `n-1`, so total is `O(n * (n + 1) / 2) = O(n ^ 2)`.

Comment: Even if I don't know exactly which is the claimed complexity for a look up into the `HashSet`, we can safely assume (as this is one of the possible implementation of the hash set) that the complexity is `O(N)` in the worst case (all the keys collide), while it's `O(1)` in the best case. The initial solution has a complexity of `O(N^2)` in any case. How can you say that there is no gain? You are performing almost certainly better than previously, aren't you?

Comment: Indeed I think you only showed us how to get the worst case complexity, but you know that the best one (likely the real one) is `O(N*1) = O(N) << O(N^2)`. Isn't it? Let me know if I'm wrong, for I'm far to be an expert on that stuff. :-)

Comment: @skypjack Actually I never said your method would be slower (and it is indeed way faster), and I did not know anything about `HashSet` complexity so I assumed your `O(n)` was representative while in fact it is more like `O(1)` (`O(n)` for a add/search in a set is very unlikely) which explain the speed. So the whole stuff complexity is probably `O(n)`.

Comment: Supplying the expected population to a constructor of a hash-based "collection" not only saves reallocation, in particular, it saves re-hashing. `Sorry, j is i indeed` would never have happened with a foreach-loop/"enhanced for-loop".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `skypjack` answer, and to provide another algorithm (and comparison), here is a dichotomic search:

```
private static int countDichotomic (String[] a) {
    int count = 0 ;
    Arrays.sort(a) ;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a[i]);
        sb.reverse();
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(a, i + 1, a.length, sb.toString()) > i)
            count ++ ;
    }
    return count ;
}
```

I am clearly not a Java developper so excuse my poor coding style...

Here is some results from the 3 method:

```
N = 10000
Original:   2113ms
HashSet:    7ms
Dichotomic: 10ms

N = 100000
Original:   Unknow (too long)
HashSet:    83ms
Dichotomic: 147ms

N = 1000000
Original:   Unknow (too long)
HashSet:    1137ms
Dichotomic: 1951ms
```

**Important note:** These results are for string of length `20`, which is short. The difference between the `HashSet` and the `Dichotomic` methods becomes shorter and shorter as the length of the string increse. On my computer, `Dichotomic` method reaches `HashSet` for a string length about `1000`, and the gap between the two increases with the string length:

```
N = 100000
L = 20
HashSet:    83ms
Dichotomic: 147ms
L = 100
HashSet:    115ms
Dichotomic: 167ms
L = 300
HashSet:    169ms
Dichotomic: 238ms
L = 500
HashSet:    262ms
Dichotomic: 319ms
L = 1000
HashSet:    384ms
Dichotomic: 386ms
L = 5000
HashSet:    1866ms
Dichotomic: 895ms
```

The code I used to compute time:

```
long startTime, endTime, count = 0 ;
double duration ;
startTime = System.nanoTime();
count = countMethod (arrayOfStrings);
endTime = System.nanoTime();
duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000 ;
System.out.println("Original: " + count + ", " + duration + "ms");
```

I use randomized strings so I get a total count of 0 (looking at the algorithm, I don't think it would change the result). Still, I am not a Java expert so there could be a better method to bench these functions.

**Important note:** I have computed time for only 1 instance, which is not really accurate, but for the results I obtained, there are not many variation between 2 instances (and I didnot have the time to write a really accurate program... ).

Here is the whole code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class PalindromeSearch {

    private static String random () {
        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static int N_String = 1000000 ;

    private static int countOriginal (String[] a) {
        int count = 0 ;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {           
            for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++)
            {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a[j]);
                sb = sb.reverse();

                if(a[i].equals(sb.toString()))
                    count++;
            }
        }
        return count ;
    }

    private static int countHashSet (String[] a) {
        int count = 0 ;
        Set<String> def = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> rev = new HashSet<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a[i]);
            sb.reverse();
            String srev = sb.toString();

            if(rev.contains(a[i]) || def.contains(srev))
                ++count;

            def.add(a[i]);
            rev.add(srev);
        }
        return count ;
    }

    private static int countDichotomic (String[] a) {
        int count = 0 ;
        Arrays.sort(a) ;

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a[i]);
            sb.reverse();
            if (Arrays.binarySearch(a, i + 1, a.length, sb.toString()) > i)
                count ++ ;
        }
        return count ;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arrayOfStrings = new String[N_String] ;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < arrayOfStrings.length ; i++) {
            arrayOfStrings[i] = random () ;
        }

        // arrayOfStrings = new String[] {"html", "xml", "lmth", "css", "lmx", "xhtml"} ;

        long startTime, endTime, count = 0 ;
        double duration ;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        // count = countOriginal (arrayOfStrings);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000 ;  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
        System.out.println("Original: " + count + ", " + duration + "ms");

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        count = countHashSet(arrayOfStrings);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000 ;  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
        System.out.println("HashSet: " + count + ", " + duration + "ms");

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        count = countDichotomic(arrayOfStrings);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000 ;  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
        System.out.println("Dichotomic: " + count + ", " + duration + "ms");
    }

}
```